# code not working as expected in chrome debugger

Tags: angular, typescript

I encounter a strange behaviour in my typescript project (angular application). I have this code:

```
const idx = myclone.findIndex(x => x.id === action.id);
const hasVal = idx>-1; // this line gets skipped by chrome debugger
if (idx>-1) { // this will always be false, even though idx===0
  myclone[idx].upload = action.status;
  return {
    ...state,
    ProgressFiles: myclone,
  };
} else {
  return state; // this branch is used even if idx > -1
}
```

there seems to be something wrong with line 2 (a debug addition) and 3, but I cannot figure out what it is. To me it looks like valid code, but chrome debugger will skip line 2 and also always evaluate the if expression to false, although idx === 0. What is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Try putting a `debugger;` statement after Line 2.

**Explanation:**
This behavior is most probably caused by a minor issue in source maps generated by the angular version you're using.

Source maps are mappers (mostly in the form of JS comments) that some browsers & IDEs can read. These mappers link between the actual built file (the code that actually runs in browser) & your code files (ex: .ts).

You may already know that TypeScript doesn't run by default in the browser environment so it goes through transpilation & some other steps and a source map is auto-generated by angular in development mode to make sure you can debug it.

So the debugger reads the generated JS code and the source maps and it maps the lines running to the lines in the TypeScript files. The files may look a little bit different (some lines missing, some lines added). The debugger might miss some lines due to poor source maps. But it shouldn't be too far off your debugging goals.

Anyway, the debugger statement makes sure that you get your break-point exactly where needed.